# Custom Teams Office 365 Connector cannot be setup

Tags: office365connectors, teams-toolkit

### The problem

I am trying to build a configurable team tab with a custom connector but having serious issues when the teams app is installed and try to configure the connector.  I created tab apps and they work fine. But the connector, on its own or with a tab fails to config.

The connector custom configuration page is opened in a new window and shows the config page but the Teams SDK does not initialize.  The `microsoftTeams.initialize()` function doesn't seem to do anything. Callbacks for functions like `microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings(settings)` and `microsoftTeams.settings.getSettings()` are never called.

I have tried dozens of samples and both node.js and csharp projects. I have tried building connectors in the teams app builder, yo teams, and VSCode Teams Toolkit. I even tried different versions of the teams SDK.  Made no difference.

I read all the SO questions and Teams SDK github issues and none of those suggestions or solutions made a difference.

**Does anyone know if custom created Office 365 Connectors still work in Teams or what I am doing wrong?**

Could it be my sandbox teams/office environment?

### Here is my configuration:

- Created a sandbox Office/Teams dev environment with fake users + Azure per
  the docs. *I have not tried production Teams/Office yet*.
- Changed the Teams admin setting to allow sideloading
- Created connector registration (created multiple times, not edited)
  on outlook.office.com.
- Created the connector config page (in a few
  different ways) Hosted on ngrok (and azure - made no difference)
- Uploaded app in "Manage Your Apps" -> "Upload Custom App"
- Select a Team channel to install the app
- Configured connector in the Team Channel
- Clicked "Visit Site To Install" link
- Config page opens but none of the Teams SDK works - I added console.log everywhere to verify

##### Manifest:

*This is the default Quick scaffolded `yo teams` configurable tab and connector*

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.9/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.9",
  "id": "c8012880-98bc-11ec-bee3-ab9042a78ecb",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "packageName": "tabappl",
  "developer": {
    "name": "mytest",
    "websiteUrl": "https://48fb-80-233-63-141.ngrok.io",
    "privacyUrl": "https://48fb-80-233-63-141.ngrok.io/privacy.html",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://48fb-80-233-63-141.ngrok.io/tou.html"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "tabappl",
    "full": "tabappl"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "TODO: add short description here",
    "full": "TODO: add full description here"
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "icon-outline.png",
    "color": "icon-color.png"
  },
  "accentColor": "#D85028",
  "configurableTabs": [
    {
      "configurationUrl": "https://48fb-80-233-63-141.ngrok.io/tab1Tab/config.html?name={loginHint}&tenant={tid}&group={groupId}&theme={theme}",
      "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
      "scopes": [
        "team"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "staticTabs": [],
  "bots": [],
  "connectors": [
    {
      "connectorId": "76a7925f-e99f-4d9e-970b-b1bee2390f2c",
      "configurationUrl": "https://48fb-80-233-63-141.ngrok.io/tabapplConnector/config.html?name={loginHint}&tenant={tid}&group={groupId}&theme={theme}",
      "scopes": [
        "team"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "composeExtensions": [],
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
  ],
  "validDomains": [
    "https://48fb-80-233-63-141.ngrok.io"
  ],
  "showLoadingIndicator": false
}
```

##### The connector registration manifest (exported from outlook.office.com reg)

*Connector is just registered, not published*

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.3/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.3",
  "id": "76a7925f-e99f-4d9e-970b-b1bee2390f2c",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "packageName": "com.tabappCon2",
  "developer": {
    "name": "Developer",
    "websiteUrl": "https://48fb-80-233-63-141.ngrok.io",
    "privacyUrl": "https://48fb-80-233-63-141.ngrok.io",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://48fb-80-233-63-141.ngrok.io"
  },
  "description": {
    "full": "tabappCon2",
    "short": "tabappCon2"
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "https://outlook.office.com/connectors/Content/Images/IncomingWebhook.jpg",
    "color": "https://outlook.office.com/connectors/Content/Images/IncomingWebhook.jpg"
  },
  "connectors": [
    {
      "connectorId": "76a7925f-e99f-4d9e-970b-b1bee2390f2c",
      "scopes": [
        "team"
      ],
      "configurationUrl": "https://48fb-80-233-63-141.ngrok.io/tabapplConnector/config.html"
    }
  ],
  "name": {
    "full": "tabappCon2",
    "short": "tabappCon2"
  },
  "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
  "validDomains": [
    "https://48fb-80-233-63-141.ngrok.io"
  ],
  "needsIdentity": "true"
}
```

Comment: To add to the above,  I tested in Chrome and Edge on windows and mac.  Also tried the Teams application on windows and Mac.  Doesnt work on any of those. 
Note that it shows `https://` in the `validDomains` above but I also tried without `https://` in the reg and app manifest.  No luck there either.

Comment: I think I'm having the same problem with a connector which was working earlier, and is no longer, in the way you describe. Actually, for me the symptom is that the `microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate(...)` call opens in a new window (breaking the login flow), but searching back I find that this is the root cause: failing initialization. I believe there is an open issue behind this: https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-library-js/issues/617#issuecomment-1063721976